# Проблема с получением адреса Google Maps Geocode

Tags: php, google-maps-api, google-maps

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" . $latitude .",". $longitude ."&sensor=false&key=API_KEY
Проблема такая, получаю в ответ неправильный адрес, как исправить?

Пример того, что я получаю

```
    {
   "plus_code" : {
      "compound_code" : "5C9R+3C Yerevan, Armenia",
      "global_code" : "8HG65C9R+3C"
   },
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "жилое",
               "short_name" : "жилое",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bangladesh",
               "short_name" : "Bangladesh",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Yerevan",
               "short_name" : "Yerevan",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Yerevan",
               "short_name" : "Yerevan",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Armenia",
               "short_name" : "AM",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "жилое, Yerevan, Armenia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1678554,
                  "lng" : 44.4411725
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1674516,
                  "lng" : 44.4409767
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.1676558,
               "lng" : 44.4410813
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1690024802915,
                  "lng" : 44.4424235802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1663045197085,
                  "lng" : 44.4397256197085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJN4orDd-9akARr_CHIzBo7uE",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Unnamed Road",
               "short_name" : "Unnamed Road",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bangladesh",
               "short_name" : "Bangladesh",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Yerevan",
               "short_name" : "Yerevan",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Yerevan",
               "short_name" : "Yerevan",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Armenia",
               "short_name" : "AM",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Unnamed Road, Yerevan, Armenia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1678113,
                  "lng" : 44.4409177
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1671363,
                  "lng" : 44.4394916
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.1673747,
               "lng" : 44.440349
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1688227802915,
                  "lng" : 44.4415536302915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1661248197085,
                  "lng" : 44.4388556697085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJX5kLet-9akARxu92iLmBBCk",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "B1",
               "short_name" : "B1",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Malatia-Sebastia",
               "short_name" : "Malatia-Sebastia",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Yerevan",
               "short_name" : "Yerevan",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Yerevan",
               "short_name" : "Yerevan",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Armenia",
               "short_name" : "AM",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "B1, Yerevan, Armenia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1738564,
                  "lng" : 44.4460917
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1651662,
                  "lng" : 44.4371009
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.1698302,
               "lng" : 44.441828
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1738564,
                  "lng" : 44.4460917
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1651662,
                  "lng" : 44.4371009
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJE4fvRt69akARZwyHPF6rPiA",
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Malatia-Sebastia",
               "short_name" : "Malatia-Sebastia",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Yerevan",
               "short_name" : "Yerevan",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Yerevan",
               "short_name" : "Yerevan",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Armenia",
               "short_name" : "AM",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Malatia-Sebastia, Yerevan, Armenia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.2256632,
                  "lng" : 44.48988139999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1447431,
                  "lng" : 44.3619347
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.1686452,
               "lng" : 44.45749199999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.2256632,
                  "lng" : 44.48988139999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.1447431,
                  "lng" : 44.3619347
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJcabfJdG9akARS3WuMhvvZcI",
         "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Yerevan",
               "short_name" : "Yerevan",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Yerevan",
               "short_name" : "Yerevan",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Armenia",
               "short_name" : "AM",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Yerevan, Armenia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.2426667,
                  "lng" : 44.6150493
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.0641141,
                  "lng" : 44.3620849
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.1872023,
               "lng" : 44.515209
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.2426667,
                  "lng" : 44.6150493
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.0641141,
                  "lng" : 44.3620849
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJW4v8uNqiakARalLah655FD0",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Yerevan",
               "short_name" : "Yerevan",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Armenia",
               "short_name" : "AM",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Yerevan, Armenia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.261712,
                  "lng" : 44.66696109999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.08440600000001,
                  "lng" : 44.416932
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.1794197,
               "lng" : 44.5408413
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.261712,
                  "lng" : 44.66696109999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.08440600000001,
                  "lng" : 44.416932
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJc-dHAcOiakAR9TDRSvqQzRU",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Armenia",
               "short_name" : "AM",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Armenia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 41.300993,
                  "lng" : 46.6342219
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 38.840244,
                  "lng" : 43.4472601
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.069099,
               "lng" : 45.038189
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 41.300993,
                  "lng" : 46.6342219
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 38.840244,
                  "lng" : 43.4472601
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJx7pz54RWFUARIy2C63p1tNA",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

вместо номера и адреса дома получаю "жилой дом".
К примеру на сайте https://www.gps-coordinates.net , который также использует гугл мапс, все адреса правильно выводятся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По данному району Еревана у Гугл нет информации о номерах домов.
https://www.google.ru/maps/@40.1676681,44.440202,19.39z 
Зато на ОСМ есть номера домов
https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/40.16770/44.44048
Тут 2 варианта решения. 
1. Сделать геокодер на основе ОСМ и других доступных данных на интересующую область.
Плюс подхода в том, что вы получаете независимость, гибкость, возможность редактировать и дополнять информацию, улучшая результат.
2. Использовать готовые сторонние сервисы, типа https://opencagedata.com 
Плюс подхода в быстроте подключения. Не нужно разрабатывать API и анализировать данные.

Можно сочетать оба варианта, проверяя результат, выводить лучший.

Answer (score 2):

У гугла такое может быть, не использовав другие сервисы вы не сможете определить адрес. http://joxi.ru/1A5Go11tDQjlqm т.е. даже на google maps нет адресов у зданий. А https://www.gps-coordinates.net/ использует https://opencagedata.com/ что вы можете собственно и использовать вместо гугла, сервис даёт 2500 запросов в день бесплатно, гугл даёт 70 000 запросов в месяц бесплатно.

Посмотреть работу демо можно тут https://opencagedata.com/demo